# OSX Push Notifications for Websites - Safari requestPermission callback never called

Tags: macos, safari, apple-push-notifications

Following the instructions as per [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/NotificationProgrammingGuideForWebsites/PushNotifications/PushNotifications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013225-CH3-SW1) to allow a user with Safari to visit a website and get Push Notifications for the Apple Push Notification Service.

I'm using SSL, have a certificate from Apple, and have generated the push package file.

Safari downloads this when running the prompt `requestPermission`, displays the user permission request prompt, but on the user clicking 'approve', the callback function is never called.

```
window.safari.pushNotification.requestPermission(url, websitePushID, userInfo, callback);
```

1. The callback function is never called.
2. No exceptions are thrown.
3. No POST is made to the server for any success or error.
4. The website is now listed under System Preferences > Notifications.
5. The website is **not** listed under Notifications within Safari Preferences.
6. Further attempts to requestPermission or query permission are denied instantly.

The only way to reset the denied permission is to edits OSXs internal sqllite file and delete a bunch of config files within Safari before I can retry the request.

**What could be causing this unusual behaviour?**

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to judge without the exact javascript you are using, but the 3 permission types that you see in the apple documentaion are default, granted and denied.

If the permission is granted or denied, then the user has already set whether they want to receive these push notifications.  Once a user has denied a push notification then Apple has made the decision that they cannot be asked again (without changing settings.)  If they already have been granted permission there is no need to call window.safari.pushNotification.requestPermission

The only time that you would call window.safari.pushNotification.requestPermission is when permission has neither been denied nor granted.  Only in this case will you want to call the function and expect for a response to trigger the callback function.  If you see a permission request prompt it means the requestionPermission has worked.

Comment: The permission is at 'default' before the requestPermission is called, but still the callback is never made.  The code being run is literally as in the sample, with just callback writing it's arguments to the console.  I've a bug report open with Apple.

Comment: @simbolo did you ever come to a resolution?  we're seeing the same thing.

Comment: @Casey Nope! I opened a number of developer tech support cases only to be told that Safari is not a supported product. So there is an open bug report (#17565372) that is still open after all these months. In the end I gave up on the implementation as was never able to work out why it didn't work. Some comfort was given that I couldn't subscribe to any other websites either, so it's not just me. I concluded that something broke Safari in Mavericks and it still remains broken to this day.